# fuerte rospack package/stack not found

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, today i found that my "rospack" cannot find any existing package / stack inside my sandbox! My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is correct, so I don't know what's wrong with my fuerte, and I am using Ubuntu12.04... because yesterday i tried to install Moveit (for groovy) into my fuerte,  does it matter? and I want to know how to fix it!... thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64660/fuerte-rospack-package/stack-not-found/) by [BerylZhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5104/berylzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add it again.

```
$ rospack profile
$ rospack find package
```

It could be that Moveit has overwritten some things in your bashrc but if the rest of the package paths are okay this is not the problem.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0